# Sending xml using php

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have a xml file on my server. I have the following two questions.

1. How to send this xml file using php to the clients browser ?
2. The client would be making an ajax get request to the php script that sends the xml as a response. On the server side i use php simplexml functions to parse xml data. But, on the client end what would be the best way to parse the xml data ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use these two commands:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
readfile('/path/to/file.xml');
```

You didn't say anything about receiving XML on the server, so I'm not sure what you mean by parsing.

Regarding parsing XML in JavaScript... I defer to someone with more experience.

Comment: I believe the function you're looking for is `readfile()`, rather than `passthru()`.  (`fpassthru()` would also work, if you had a file handle rather than a path to the file.)

Answer (score 2):

gahooa's code to send the XML file to the client should work just fine. In JavaScript, you can use the [XML parser](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp) to read and manipulate it. However, this is **not** the approach I would recommend.

**Instead**, let the server [convert your XML into JSON](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/) after using PHP's `file_get_contents()` to read the XML to a string. JavaScript can natively [evaluate JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html).

You'll find that navigating the DOM of an XML is clumsy by comparison to working with native JSON.

Comment: @Dolph: Just curious to know, will the conversion to JSON also result in performance improvement on client side?

Comment: Without testing/researching, I would say yes. Because JSON is a native data type, it can parse the data without interpreting/running any JavaScript. Instead, the browser's JavaScript engine (written in C++, etc) would do the parsing. For XML, it would be a JavaScript library doing the parsing, and then you're interpreting/running lots of extra, *relatively* slow JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

set the content type in the HTTP response using the header() function as:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

then you can write the xml file content.

You must call hearder() **before** any output is sent.

On client side you can parse the XML in JavaScript using DOM.